# CUDA 2d convolution boundary incorrect

Tags: cuda

I implemented a CUDA 2D convolution code with naive way and cannot get the boundary value correct.  The error happens on the top and left borders with half-of-filter wide. For example, if my filter is 7x7, the error reside in top 3 pixels and left 3 pixels (compared to C result).  Can some one help me to resolve this bug?  Your help is very appreciated!

Attached is my cuda code and c code:

```
#define ISIZE 32//input image size ISIZE*ISIZE
#define MASK_RADIUS 3
#define MASK_WIDTH (2 * MASK_RADIUS + 1)
const int FILTER_SIZE = MASK_WIDTH * MASK_WIDTH * sizeof(float);
__device__ __constant__ float d_filter[FILTER_SIZE];

__global__ void convolution2D_cuda(float* d_Result, float* d_Data, int dataH, int dataW)
{
// global mem address for this thread
const int gLoc = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x +
                 (threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y) * dataW; 

float sum = 0;
float value = 0;

for(int i = -MASK_RADIUS; i <= MASK_RADIUS; i++) //row wise
{ 
    for (int j = -MASK_RADIUS; j <= MASK_RADIUS; j++) //col wise
    { 
        // check row 
        if ( (blockIdx.x == 0) && ((threadIdx.x + j) < 0) ) //left apron
            value = 0;
        else if ( blockIdx.x == (gridDim.x -1) && (threadIdx.x + j) > (blockDim.x-1) ) //right apron
            value = 0;          
        else {
            // check col
            if ( blockIdx.y == 0 && (threadIdx.y + i) < 0) //top apron
                value = 0;
            else if ( blockIdx.y == (gridDim.y-1) && (threadIdx.y + i) > (blockDim.y-1) ) //bottom apron
                value = 0;
            else // load data
                value = d_Data[gLoc + i * dataW + j];
        }
        //2d array case: non-separable filter
        sum += value * d_filter[ (MASK_RADIUS - i) * MASK_WIDTH + (MASK_RADIUS - j) ];
    }
}
d_Result[gLoc] = sum;
}

//c code
void convolution2D_cpu(float* result, float* input, float* filter, int dataW, int dataH, int k_Width, int k_Height, int radiusY, int radiusX)
{
      int y, x, ky, kx;
      for (y = 0; y < dataH; y++) { //row
         for (x = 0; x < dataW; x++) {
         result[y*dataW + x] = 0;
         float sum=0;
         for(ky = -radiusY; ky <= radiusY; ky++) {
                 for(kx = -radiusX; kx <= radiusX; kx++) {
                int dy = y + ky;
            int dx = x + kx;
            if (dy >= 0 && dy < dataH) //left & upper borders
                if (dx >= 0 && dx < dataW) //right & lower borders
            sum += input[dy*dataW + dx] * filter[(radiusY-ky)*k_Width + (radiusX - kx)];            
                }
            }
        result[y*dataW+x] = sum;
        }
    }
}



Part of the main() code is :

    dim3 blocks(16, 16);
dim3 grids(width/16, height/16);


    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_data, data_size ));
checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_result, data_size ));
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(d_data, indata, data_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    checkCudaErrors( cudaThreadSynchronize() );

convolution2D_cuda<<<grids, blocks>>>(d_result, d_data, width, height);
    checkCudaErrors( cudaThreadSynchronize() );

    checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(output, d_result, data_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    checkCudaErrors( cudaThreadSynchronize() );

    //check with result of CPU
    convolution2D_cpu(c_result, indata, filter, width, height, len, len, MASK_RADIUS, MASK_RADIUS);
```

Comment: What are the block and grid dimensions you use? Can you also give the part of the code where you call the kernel?

Comment: Just a simple question, on the CPU part you got two different loops with different boundaries (`radiusY`, `radiusX`) but on the GPU part you got only one boundary on your loops (`MASK_RADIUS`) it might be the error, no? As the main code isn't complete. I couldn't give a conclusion on it. But it might.

Comment: Yes, the radiusX and radiusY are set to equal to MASK_RADIUS for the test.

Comment: the size of your array `d_filter[FILTER_SIZE]` is not correct. That should be `d_filter[FILTER_SIZE/sizeof(float)]`

Comment: your grid has the size of your image?

Comment: Hi, The size of d_filter[FILTER_SIZE] is correct.  The problem is I got "Memory Check detected 32 access violation" error message in CUDA MEMCHECK.  My question is how to get the thread index correct in this naive implementation? Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: The test case is 32x32 image with 7x7 filter.  16x16 thread block and 2x2 grid.

Comment: I get to resolve this mystery. The error happens on thread index calculation.  threadIdx is uint, nvcc thinks (threadIdx.x + j) as unsigned int.  Ex. if j is -1, it is interpreted as 4294967295 (ffffffff) and the boundary index is incorrect.

Comment: Why not post your discovery as an answer.  That way it will help others and we can mark this question as answered.  You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get to resolve this mystery. The error happens on thread index calculation. threadIdx is uint, nvcc thinks (threadIdx.x + j) as unsigned int. Ex. if j is -1, it is interpreted as 4294967295 (ffffffff) and the boundary index is incorrect.